# Calculate the closest summation to X using a list of numbers

Tags: python, algorithm, numbers

I have a list of numbers

```
[850, 1300, 810, 590, 590, 910, 480, 1170, 430, 530, 295, 970, 560, 410, 570, 680, 180, 180, 400, 1040]
```

I want to give the function an integer argument and have it return the closest number possible by summing numbers in the list, and telling me which numbers it used to achieve this.

For example, I give it the number 3255, and it will spit out something like

```
1300, 810, & 1170 sum to 3280
```

(I'm not sure if this is the actual closest combination from this example, just showing how it should work)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you want us to write some code for you. While many users are willing to produce code for a coder in distress, they usually only help when the poster has already tried to solve the problem on their own. A good way to demonstrate this effort is to include the code you've written so far, example input (if there is any), the expected output, and the output you actually get (console output, stack traces, compiler errors - whatever is applicable). The more detail you provide, the more answers you are likely to receive.

Comment: Check out `itertools`, specifically `itertools.combinations`.

Comment: It seems that this problem is similar to the [backpack problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) which is rather hard to solve efficiently. The wikipedia article lists a few ways to solve it, including some pseudocode.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to brute-force the problem, use a modified powerset recipe from [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
import itertools as it

def powerset(iterable):
    "powerset([1,2,3]) --> (1,) (2,) (3,) (1,2) (1,3) (2,3) (1,2,3)"
    s = list(iterable)
    return it.chain.from_iterable(it.combinations(s, r) for r in range(1, len(s)+1))

def f(n, lst):
    return min((abs(n-sum(i)), i) for i in powerset(lst))[1]
```

This approach doesn't work for initial lists much larger than your example list though because powersets grow exponentially.

Answer (score 0):

The following is the pseudo code that executes in better complexity than brute force

Assuming the input array is arr[], there is a stack to store output

```
recurse(n, index)
{
    int temp = n; int ind = index;
    while(ind<arr.length)
        if(arr[ind]>n)
            ind++;
        else
            temp = temp - arr[ind];
            stack.push(temp);
            if(temp==0)
                return true;
            result = recurse(temp,ind+1);
            if(result is false)
                temp = n; stack.pop();
                ind++;
            else
                break;
    if(ind==arr.length) then return false
}
print stack
```

Example:
If the array is the following
11 9 8 7 5
and you need to find 26
then it executes as follows

recurse(26,0)
26-11 -> recurse(15,1) since 26-11 = 15; pushes 11 in stack
recurse(15,1)
15-9 -> recurse(6,2) since 15-9 = 6; pushes 9 in stack
recurse(6,2)
6-5 -> recurse(1,4) pushes 5 in stack
recurse(1,4) returns false because there is no element smaller than 1 pops 5 from stack
since there is no element smaller than 6 other than 5, pops 9 from stack
now it computes 15-8 = 7 recurse(7,3), pushes 8 in stack
recurse(7,3) pushes 7 in stack returns true

Finally it prints stack 11, 8, 7 where 11 + 8 + 7 = 26